# Bigquery external table metadata

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to extract bigquery external table metadata.
I've gone through [documetation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables)

But I'm not able to find the field which gives me the information related to the external table location on gcs.
So is there any other metadata table that gives me location information of the external table?

Answer (score 0):

Using `SPLIT` since there can be multiple comma separated uris:

```sql
SELECT ddl, SPLIT(REGEXP_EXTRACT(ddl, r"(?i)uris\s*=\s*\[(.*)\]")) as uris
FROM `catalog.schema.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
WHERE table_type = 'EXTERNAL';
```